# Borel-Cantelli Lemma Proof Verification

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, borel-cantelli-lemmas, measurable-sets

> **Exercise 16 (Stein): The Borel-Cantelli Lemma: Suppose $\{E_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is a countable family of measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and that
> \begin{equation*}
>  \sum_{k=1}^\infty m(E_k) < \infty.
> \end{equation*}
> Let**
> \begin{align*}
>  E = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^d : x \in E_k, \text{ for infinitely many } k \}\\
>  = \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \sup (E_k).
> \end{align*}
> **Show that $E$ is measurable.**

**Remark:** Now, after looking at some resources I now understand that the proof of this extremely simple once one remembers that the set of measurable sets is a $\sigma$-algebra, however I was curious if the proof I have worked out is also true. Any suggestions on writing proofs in general is always welcome of course!

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. First, recall that the countable union of measurable sets is itself measurable, and notice that
\begin{equation*}
 m\biggr(\bigcup_{k = j}^\infty E_k \biggr) \leq \sum_{k=j}^\infty m(E_k) < \sum_{k=1}^\infty m(E_k) < \infty,
\end{equation*}
for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$. Now consider the following decreasing sequence
\begin{equation*}
 \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k \supset \bigcup_{k=2}^\infty E_k \supset \dots \supset \bigcup_{k=N}^\infty E_k \supset \dots \supset E.
\end{equation*}
From Corollary 3.3, since the sequence decreases to $E$ and $\displaystyle m\biggr(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k\biggr) < \infty$, it follows that
\begin{equation*}
 m(E) = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\biggr(\bigcup_{k = N}^\infty E_k\biggr).
\end{equation*}
Thus it follows that there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $\epsilon' = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$,
\begin{equation*}
 m\biggr(\bigcup_{j=N}^\infty E_j \setminus E \biggr) < \epsilon'. 
\end{equation*}
Moreover, notice that since each $\bigcup_{j=k}^\infty E_j$ is measurable for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$, it follows that there exists an $\mathcal{O}_N$ for $N$ such that for $\epsilon''=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$
\begin{equation*}
 m\biggr(\mathcal{O}_n \setminus \bigcup_{j=N}^\infty E_j\biggr) < \epsilon''.
\end{equation*}
Therefore, we can conclude that then there exists $\mathcal{O}_N$ such that
\begin{equation*}
 m(\mathcal{O}_N - E) = m\biggr(\mathcal{O}_n \setminus \bigcup_{j=N}^\infty E_j\biggr) + m\biggr(\bigcup_{j=N}^\infty E_j \setminus E \biggr) < \epsilon' + \epsilon'' = \epsilon.
\end{equation*}
Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, it follows that $E$ is a measurable set.

**Remark 2:** The second part of the Borel-Cantelli Lemma ($m(E) = 0$) is clear as if this were not true the hypothesis of the finiteness of the sum of the measure of the members of the family would not hold.

Comment: What do you mean by $\sum_{k=1}^\infty E_k<\infty$?

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín oops that was a typo, I edited the above post. Meant $\sum_{k=1}^\infty m(E_k) < \infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$E= \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty  E_k$ (why?)
Hence, $E$ is trivially measurable by the axioms of $\sigma$-algebra. The assumption $\sum_k m(E_k) < \infty$ is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $E=\bigcap_n\bigcup_{m\geq n}E_m$. Measurability follows immediately.

If you meant to say "prove that $E$ has $\mu$ measure zero, then  that follows from monotone convergence since
$$
\int_X\sum_{k}\mathbb{1}_{E_k}\,d\mu\stackrel{MCT}{=}\sum_k\int_X\mathbb{1}_{E_k}\,d\mu=\sum_k\mu(E_k)<\infty$$
Notice that  $E=\Big\{\sum_k\mathbb{1}_{E_k}=\infty\Big\}= \bigcap_n\bigcup_{k\geq n}E_k$. Since $f=\sum_n\mathbb{1}_{E_k}$ is integrable
$$\mu(E)=\mu(|f|=\infty)=0$$

Comment: I guess indeed that the OP meant to prove that $m(E) = 0$ (given the name Borel-Cantelli and the assumption on the series). (+1)